# a word which means extremely ignorant

Tags: adjectives

Is there an adjective which means "extremely ignorant"? For instance, in Turkish "cahil" means "ignorant" and "zircahil" means "extremely ignorant".

Comment: A great many words and phrases that mean that. People over the centuries have delighted in inventing words for it. A context/occasion for where it would be used would help narrow down which might be appropriate.

Comment: We don't have extreme ignorance in English. Or else I am extremely ignorant of the word for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not an adjective, I think "ignoramus" would suit.

Comment: Hi Kryten. This is a good suggestion and has my upvote. To make it a good _post_, you should add a link to a free online dictionary, cite it, and quote the definition in your post. That is the norm here. Feel free to browse some [single word request questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) to see what I mean. You'll find many examples of good posts. Thank you.

Comment: The norm should not be about citing a dictionary, it should be about clarifying your answer with an explanation. Referring to and quoting from a dictionary are ways to do that, but not the only way.